# nodejs cannot POST /api/signup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying this tutorial from youtube:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ECVE6TXKLQ&list=PLI-gk4ISRzCPlJjCz3yuAhL8vnmK6KWr7&index=11

so far I have a server listening on port 8080 I'm connected to MongoDB atlas database and it worked fine, my next step is to make an API to do signup so here's my code:

### server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var config = require('./config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();


mongoose.connect(config.database,{ useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false},function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Connected to the Database");
    }
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

var api = require('./app/routes/api')(app, express);
api.use('/api',api);

app.get('*',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});


app.listen(config.port,function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
    console.log("Listening on port 8080");
    }
});
```

### user.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var UserSchema = new Schema({

    name: String,
    email: {type: String, required: true, index:{unique: true}},
    password: {type: String, required: true, select: false},
    status: String

});
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){

    var user = this;

    if(!user.isModified('password')) return next(); 

    bcrypt.hash(user.password,null,null,function(err, hash){
        if(err) return next(err);

        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password){
    var user = this;

    return bcrypt.compareSync(password,user.password);
}
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

### api.js:

```
var User = require('../models/user');

var config = require('../../config');

var secretKey = config.secretKey;


module.exports = function(app, express){


    var api = express.Router();

    api.post('/signup',function(req, res){

        var user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
            status: req.body.status
        });

        user.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }

            res.json({message: 'User Has Been Created!'});
        });
    });

    return api

}
```

that code so far worked perfectly for the tutorial guy, as he tested it on postman where I typed the URL: localhost:8080/api/signup

changed the operation from *GET* to *POST* and added the appropriate parameters.

Below is a screenshot of what I'm doing on postman in order to test it.

and the output is

> Cannot POST from  /api/signup

I have also attached the console output at the last.

I have literally no background using javascript node js or anything else used in this tutorial so I don't know where to start looking for the error.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Did you restart your node server after changing the code?

Comment: Yes I did each time, still it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line in your `server.js` file:

```js
api.use('/api',api);
```

to

```js
app.use('/api',api);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and good luck with NodeJS! 